# How to add wind vectors over a density heatmap?

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

I have this density heatmap generated using Python Plotly package:

[image]

Now I need to add wind vectors over the heatmap. I would like to use [quiver plots](https://plotly.com/python/quiver-plots/) if possible, but currently I want to know how to add any kind of plot to a mapbox.

I have only found [this example](https://blog.plotly.com/post/171585173862/how-to-create-2d-and-3d-interactive-weather-maps) but the source code in the [Plotly Chart Studio](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Eempet/14795/wind-speed-forecast/) doesn't load so I don't know how to do it, also I need it in 2D:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure if it is helpful but there is a software called QGIS (it's free). It is much easier to work with geospatial data there. Also, try `rasterio` library. It may have some functions like that (library for geospatial analyze)

Answer (score 0):

I once used the velocity capability of ipyleaflet https://ipyleaflet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/velocity.html

It is not using plotly but could be a good replacement for this kind of map until you find a better solution.

Comment: Hey welcome to stack overflow, a link does not suffice as an answer! If you would like to help them out you can use information from that link but just posting one isnt valid.